# Why are my VMware Workstation "VM" menu items greyed out?

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, vsphere

I'm using vSphere v8.0 and access the console of the VM through VMware Workstation v17.0.

The VM is access remotely, it is hosted on vSphere/ESXi.

[image: VMware Workstation "VM" menu items greyed out]

Is there a parameter in the `.vmx` file preventing the use the VMware Workstation VM menu knowing I've never edited the `.vmx` file manually ?

Comment: is the VM actually running locally in Workstation, or are you using vSphere to connect to a VM running remotely?

Comment: The VM menu is empty when there's no current VM.

Comment: @harrymc I clone VMware Workstation and opened it back again and somehow the VM menu reappeared on the VM : INCOMPREHENSIBLE :(.

Comment: @FrankThomas The VM is hosted on vSphere/ESXi.

Comment: If the problem no longer exists, you'd better delete the question.

Comment: @harrymc If close it, will it still be there to read ?

Comment: No. However, there is little value in keeping a question around that is extremely likely to result from a bug affecting few users.

Comment: No. If you wish to keep it, put up an answer, and later mark it as accepted. We're a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Added this just to keep this question readable :

I closed VMware Workstation and opened it back again and somehow the VMware Workstation VM menu reappeared on my VM :

[image: After reopening VMware Workstation]

INCOMPREHENSIBLE :(.